# spark-submit yarn-cluster on azure-hdinsight cannot provide additional jars (like JNR) to my app

Tags: azure, apache-spark, jar, hadoop-yarn, azure-hdinsight

I'm having problems using hdinsight spark cluster for my application which needs 2 jars,

the first one is  JNR (com.github.jnr:jnr-constants:0.9.0 exactly) 

and the other one is JNA (net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.1.0) which is required by the jruby i use.

**The problem i have is that whenever i run my app i have this error**:

```
[Error] Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : jnr.constants.platform.OpenFlags.defined()Z
```

and i have the same problem with jna if i remove my code which calls jnr

```
my.process.check.run.checkRun$.main(checkRun.scala:219): [Error] Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : com.sun.jna.Platform.is64Bit()Z
```

(`is64Bit()Z` functions is not available on jna v3.5.1)
I checked on the workers i have only this:

```
myClusterUser@wn0-Test:/$ find . -name '*jna*.jar' 2>/dev/null
./usr/lib/hdinsight-scpnet/scp/jvm/jna-3.5.1.jar
./usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/storm/extlib/jna-3.5.1.jar
myClusterUser@wn0-Test:/$ find . -name '*jnr*.jar' 2>/dev/null
myClusterUser@wn0-Test:/$
```

on the head i have this:

```
myClusterUser@hn0-Test:/$ find . -name '*jna*.jar' 2>/dev/null
./usr/lib/hdinsight-scpnet/scp/jvm/jna-3.5.1.jar
./usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/storm/extlib/jna-3.5.1.jar
myClusterUser@hn0-Test:/$ find . -name '*jnr*.jar' 2>/dev/null
myClusterUser@hn0-Test:/$
```

- I first tried to make a "fat jar" with mvn assembly to have
  everything needed included, including the good versions of jna (4.1.0) and
  jnr, i have now a 129MB jar but got the same error.
- I tried to add them on my spark submit with the `--packages option`

  ```
  spark-submit \
  --verbose \
  --packages net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.1.0,com.github.jnr:jnr- constants:0.9.0,org.jruby:jruby:9.0.1.0,com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0 \
  --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=./ \
  --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=2g \
  --conf spark.executor.memory=1500m \
  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=500 \
  --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
  --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=4 \
  --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M' \
  --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M' \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --master yarn-cluster \
  --class my.process.check.run.checkRun \
  wasb:///checkRun/my-checkRun-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
  --nostdin \
  --nodb \
  --LOG_LEVEL 0
  ```

The permsize options are there to avoid out of memory problems because the hdinsight is using java 7 and not java 8.

when i do that  i can see that on each worker i have **my-checkRun-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar** copied on yarn/local/filecache

```
myClusterUser@wn3-Test:/$ find . -name '*checkRun*.jar' 2>/dev/null
./mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/10/my-checkRun-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

and this folder contains nothing else but this jar.

i also see that spark submit retrieve the versions of the jar i specified on my `--packages` option, store them on local repository m2

then put them on a temporary WSAB (hdfs) folder alongside with a spark conf archive,

[temporary storage during run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwZZT.jpg)

 inside this archive i have the **spark_conf**.properties

```
#Spark configuration.
#Mon Jul 11 13:18:01 UTC 2016
spark.executor.memory=1500m
spark.yarn.submit.file.replication=3
spark.yarn.jar=local\:///usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/spark-assembly.jar
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=500
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=384
spark.history.kerberos.keytab=none
spark.submit.deployMode=cluster
spark.yarn.secondary.jars=net.java.dev.jna_jna-4.1.0.jar,com.github.jnr_jnr-constants-0.9.0.jar
spark.yarn.scheduler.heartbeat.interval-ms=5000
spark.yarn.preserve.staging.files=false
spark.eventLog.enabled=true
spark.executor.extraClassPath=./
spark.yarn.queue=default
spark.history.provider=org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider
spark.history.ui.port=18080
spark.yarn.historyServer.address=hn0-testr.su4ft5rezscepaqpicvo04xrkb.fx.internal.cloudapp.net\:18080
spark.master=yarn-cluster
spark.yarn.containerLauncherMaxThreads=25
spark.executor.cores=2
spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=3
spark.yarn.services=
spark.history.fs.logDirectory=wasb\:///hdp/spark-events
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=4
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX\:PermSize\=512M -XX\:MaxPermSize\=512M
spark.executor.instances=2
spark.app.name=my.process.check.run.checkRun
spark.driver.maxResultSize=2g
spark.history.kerberos.principal=none
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX\:PermSize\=512M -XX\:MaxPermSize\=512M
spark.eventLog.dir=wasb\:///hdp/spark-events
```

As you can see i have my additional jars listed on `spark.yarn.secondary.jars` parameter.

After my run i can find more jna and jnr on the head node (nothing changed on the worker nodes)

```
myClusterUser@hn0-Test:/$ find . -name '*jnr*.jar' 2>/dev/null
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jnr-netdb/jars/jnr-netdb-1.1.4.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jnr-posix/jars/jnr-posix-3.0.15.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jnr-x86asm/jars/jnr-x86asm-1.0.2.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jnr-enxio/jars/jnr-enxio-0.9.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jnr-unixsocket/jars/jnr-unixsocket-0.8.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/cache/com.github.jnr/jnr-constants/jars/jnr-constants-0.9.0.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/jars/com.github.jnr_jffi-1.2.9.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/jars/com.github.jnr_jnr-constants-0.9.0.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/jars/com.github.jnr_jnr-enxio-0.9.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/jars/com.github.jnr_jnr-x86asm-1.0.2.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/jars/com.github.jnr_jnr-netdb-1.1.4.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/jars/com.github.jnr_jnr-posix-3.0.15.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/jars/com.github.jnr_jnr-unixsocket-0.8.jar

myClusterUser@hn0-Test:/$ find . -name '*jna*.jar' 2>/dev/null
./usr/lib/hdinsight-scpnet/scp/jvm/jna-3.5.1.jar
./usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/storm/extlib/jna-3.5.1.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/cache/net.java.dev.jna/jna/jars/jna-4.1.0.jar
./home/myClusterUser/.ivy2/jars/net.java.dev.jna_jna-4.1.0.jar
```

- i tried to remove all the jars i have included with the `--packages` option just to be sure there is no conflict with it.

Does anyone got an idea about what i should do to make my run using JNA and JNR jars i provide?

Comment: The preferred way to include dependencies is to use --packages parameter. But looks like you may have conflict with different versions of the same jar that are available on the cluster. What happens when you specify --packages parameter in spark submit? What error do you get?

Comment: only the one written. in stderr i see that my jar is added to the yarn executor SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES, with the temporary hdfs storage address, then on the executor launch command i have the java command with parameters --user-class-path file:$PWD/net.java.dev.jna_jna-4.1.0.jar --user-class-path file:$PWD/com.github.jnr_jnr-constants-0.9.0.jar       I'm afraid that jnr is already included in maybe hadoop but with an older version than mine. and same thing for jna.

Comment: just to be clear: on the previous comment: in stderr i see that all the jars i'm passing with the --packages option are added to the SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES and are transmitted to the launched executor java (with option--user-class-path )